# Checking data if its present in a node

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have a 6 node cluster and I kept the replication factor as 3 and 3 for the two data centers. I inserted a single row as test and later more rows. As the replication factor is 6 I want to check if the data is written into all nodes. How can I individually check if the data is present in that node. Worst option i got is shutting down the remaining 5 nodes and checking select statement from the 1 node and repeating same on all nodes. Is there any better way to check this? THanks for your time.

Comment: I believe your wording is a little bit off.  You have a 6 node cluster, that is split between two data centers, 3 nodes per DC.  You set the keyspace to have RF3 in DC1, and RF3 in DC2.  (At no point will you have RF6.)  Then, there is the consistency Level of your reads and writes which may be CL: 1 or maybe CL: LOCAL_QUORUM, etc..... Hope that helps clarify some of the terminology.

Comment: Also, you state, "Worst option i got is shutting down the remains 5 nodes and querying the remaining node".  This will only work if your read consistency is ONE.  For example, if the consistency level is set to QUORUM or LOCAL_QUORUM, there won't be enough nodes available to reach the CL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nodetool getendpoints` for this.  Here is a sample table to keep track of Blade Runners.

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROm bladerunners;

 id     | type         | datetime                 | data
--------+--------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------
 B25881 | Blade Runner | 2015-02-16 18:00:03+0000 | Holden- Fine as long as nobody unplugs him.
 B26354 | Blade Runner | 2015-02-16 18:00:03+0000 |               Deckard- Filed and monitored.

(2 rows)
```

Now if I exit back out to my command prompt, I can use `nodetool getendpoints`, followed by my keyspace, table, and a partition key value.  The list of nodes containing data for that key should be displayed underneath:

```
aploetz@dockingBay94:~$ nodetool getendpoints stackoverflow bladerunners 'B26354'
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Hi.. I have tried bringing one node down, inserted a record into db and requesting the end points. But it showed all the 3 nodes in US eventhough one node is down. Is that expected. I mean does it take hints into acc eventhough the server is down?   2) If I bring back the node UP, how can I ensure that new record is replicated in the just UP node. Is there a way to check when the replication is happening?  Thanks

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `nodetool getendpoints` simply returns which node(s)  are *supposed to* store data having that key. It works with any key even if they don't exist in your cluster. It's doesn't really check data presence anywhere. So this doesn't exactly answer the question :)